# error: Couldn't lookup symbols: nominal type descriptor for Swift.Task.Handle trying async/await with Xcode 12.5 beta / Swift 5.5

Tags: swift, xcode12, wwdc, swift5

I'm trying to figure out how to use async/await in a Playground using Xcode 12.0 beta / Swift 5.5, but am getting an error every time.

Here's my entire playground code, which is probably wrong:

```swift
import Cocoa
import Foundation

if #available(macOS 12.0, *) {
    
    class Foo {
        func reversed(_ s: String) async -> String {
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 10)
            return String(s.reversed())
        }
    }
    
    detach {
        let foo = Foo()
        let result = await foo.reversed("Chowhound")
        print("Result is \(result)")
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
> nominal type descriptor for Swift.Task.Handle

Any solution would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

So the deal is that anything that calls `async` must also be async itself.  So if you are doing `await` *anything* in your function, that function itself must also be async.

So that would mean that everything everywhere must end up async, right?

Nope.  The solution is wrapping the calling function in `async { }`, which I learned by watching this [very helpful WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10132)

So the good code ends up being this:

```swift
import Cocoa
import Foundation

if #available(macOS 12.0, *) {
    
    class Foo {
        func reversed(_ s: String) async -> String {
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)
            return String(s.reversed())
        }
    }
    
    let foo = Foo()
    async {
        let result = await foo.reversed("Chowhound")
        print("Result is \(result)")
    }
    // The above runs asynchronously, and probably won't run before this:
    print("The async block above probably runs after me.")
}
```

The `async` wrap schedules the block within to run asynchronously, soon - a little bit like when you do DispatchQueue.main.async{}.  So in the corrected code above, the print statement at the bottom will likely run prior to async block above it.